# Mount from Debian 11 to windows 10 doesn't work

Tags: linux, debian, share, mount, cifs

On a Windows 10 host I have a VirtualBox virtual machine with Debian 11. The access to the VM is done by a virtual network card "Virtual Box Host Only Ethernet Adaptater".
I connect with ssh on my VM without any problem.

I have a shared folder on Windows 10, and I want to access it via a mount from my VM. I've been doing this for years, but now I can't get a stable behavior. It worked last week, but now it doesn't work anymore

I use this command:

```
mount -a -t cifs //192.168.56.1/vmjpweb /home/web -o "username=*******,password=*******" --verbose
```

The result :

```
/                         : ignoré
none                      : ignoré
/media/cdrom0             : ignoré
domain=192.168.56.1
password specified twice, ignoring second
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.56.1,unc=\\192.168.56.1\vmjpweb,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmsspi,uid=33,gid=33,user=*******,domain=192.168.56.1,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

The kernel  log:

```
Oct 31 09:11:49 rock kernel: [ 1009.046835] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.56.1/vmjpweb
Oct 31 09:11:49 rock kernel: [ 1009.221195] CIFS: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
Oct 31 09:11:49 rock kernel: [ 1009.221219] CIFS: VFS: \\192.168.56.1 Send error in SessSetup = -13
Oct 31 09:11:49 rock kernel: [ 1009.221263] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

Comment: I wouldn't normally use `mount -a` as well as all the parameters and options. It may just be me, but I'd either do `mount -a` without any parameters and let it pick them up from `/etc/fstab` or I'd specify all the parameters and omit `-a`.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a new local user and it works well.

The login I was using was not local on the host, but on the domain of my work. I was trying to connect to the shared folder without a connection to the domain.

I also use fstab for the running.